# How to increase height of Visual Studio IDE toolbar?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I've recently switched over to portrait screens for development so want to make more use of my vertical screen realestate.

But I can't figure out how to get Visual Studio to use more space for the toolbar.

As you can see in the image below there are lots of 'overflow' glyphs on the right, because there isn't enough space to show all the buttons. Want I want is to add extra vertical height (2x or 3x) so that I can show more buttons. Worse than that, it's hiding almost entire toolbar sections.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Doh I worked it out. There is a small resizing 'grab' icon on the left of each toolbar. You can drag that to put it on a new line. I blame the dark theme for not letting me see it :)

As for the vertical space for the toolbar, I still can't figure out how to wrap one toolbar across multiple lines. I'm guessing you can't.